# How to define a function to break an array of letters into a group of string

Tags: f#

I have C# code like this

```cs
// Class definition
Class Letter {
    char c;
    int id;
}

// A C# function to obtain an array of letters
Array[Letter] getLetters();
```

A function call from F#

```
let L = getLetters()
```

I want to break `L` into a list of strings grouped by `id`, assuming `id` starts from `0` to `N`. How can I do that in F#? I'm a F# novice.

Comment: [Seq.groupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370445.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let rslt letters = 
    letters 
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun l -> l.id) // Groups Letters into sequence of pair (id * seq<Letter>) 
    |> Seq.map (fun (_, str) -> str |> Seq.map (fun l -> l.c) ) // Maps the sequence to seq<seq<<char>> 
    |> Seq.map (fun ls -> System.String.Join("", ls)) // Maps the sequence to seq<string>
    |> List.ofSeq // Creates list of strings from seq<string>
```

Comment: How to define a function for re-use?

Comment: stdin(548,30): error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this prog
ram point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object.
 This may allow the lookup to be resolved. Why?

Comment: Hard to say without full listing. If type inference is failing use explicit type annotation: `let rslt (letters: seq<Letter>) = ...`